# The following python execute statement doesn't make sense to me, can someone explain it?

Tags: python-2.7, command-line, deep-learning

From the Github project page - https://github.com/yuanming-hu/fc4/blob/master/README.md, I'm trying to just run the application with a sample image instead of recreating the Deep Learning model myself, and I was wondering what this line of code meant.

> python2 fc4.py test pretrained/colorchecker_fold1and2.ckpt -1
>   sample_inputs/a.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find running python files from the command line confusing, particularly if you are trying to follow someone else's code.

`python2`: run the following in python2 (as opposed to python3).

`fc4.py`: Run the file [fc4.py](https://github.com/yuanming-hu/fc4/blob/master/fc4.py)

`test` gets passed to the code at the bottom of `fc4.py` which says `mode = sys.argv[1]`, so this tells `fc4.py` to run the `test` function on line 30:

```
test(name, ckpt, image_pack_name=None, output_filename=None)
```

This function uses the rest of the arguments to load the `.ckpt` file and analyse `sample_inputs/a.png`.